# Flex HTTPService going for timeout error as web service take more time to get response

Tags: apache-flex

Flex HTTPService giving timeout error as web service take more time to response. Due to large voueme 
Is there any work around to handle overcome the error

Answer (score 1):

You can try this property on the HTTPService:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html

```
requestTimeout  property     
requestTimeout:int
Provides access to the request timeout in seconds for sent messages. A value less than or equal to zero prevents request timeout.


Implementation 
    public function get requestTimeout():int
    public function set requestTimeout(value:int):void
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Flex 4.5 (possibly earlier) there's a specific fault code on the fault event for timeout errors:

In your fault handler:

```
if(faultEvent.fault.faultCode == "Client.Error.RequestTimeout"){
  trace("TIMEOUT ERROR");
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with copy and paste boilerplate answers. They tend to be flagged as "spammy", especially on older posts. Thanks.